# * is identified as a character in liquibase

Tags: sql, liquibase

I have a sql file which has the query ,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

I am trying to execute this SQL file through LIQUIBASE using the SQL tag. But it is throwing an error saying * is an unidentified character. I am unable to understand the reason. Is there any escape sequence for handling this or we can't handle such queries in LIQUIBASE.
The code in liquibase changelogfile is;

```
<changeSet author id>
 <sqlFile dbms =...
          encoding=...
          endDelimiter="\n/\s*\n*"
          path=...
          relativeChangeLogFile=...
          splitStatements=...
          StripComments=.../>
   </changeSet>
```

Comment: Can you share the code - or something - so that we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Are you trying to define the endDelimiter as a RegEx? I don't think that is supported. You need to use `endDelimiter="\n/\n"` (and make sure you don't have trailing or leading spaces on that line.

Comment: This works fine. I tried with some other sql files with trailing spaces and / they were excuted.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Can you copy and paste it? (Maybe it has to do with the encoding of the sql file? Are you using UTF?)

Comment: The exact error message is: " * is a special character"  .Yes using UTF